# Force usage of specialized subclass

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I am trying to force the usage of a more specialized class when a superclass is called with certain parameters. Concretely, I have a `Monomial` class (whose `__init__` takes the `coef`ficient and the `power`) and a `Constant` class. I wish that whenever `Monomial` is called with `power=0`, a `Constant` instance is returned instead.

The purpose of these classes is to build a framework for generating "random" mathematical functions.

What I had initially:

```
class Monomial(Function):
    def __init__(self, coef: int, power: int, inner=Identity()):
        super().__init__(inner)
        self.pow = power
        self.coef = coef


class Constant(Monomial):
    def __init__(self, c: int):
        super().__init__(c, 0)
```

I tried adding the following `__new__` method:

```
class Monomial(Function):
    def __new__(cls, coef: int, power: int, inner=Identity()):
        if power == 0:
            return Constant(coef)
        instance = object.__new__(Monomial)
        instance.__init__(coef, power, inner)
        return instance
```

The problem is that now whenever a new `Constant` is created, the `Monomial`'s `__new__` method is called (with a mismatched signature).

What's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to return a different class type when calling a class is to override the `__new__` method as opposed to `__init__`. The value returned by `__new__` is the one used as the instance (unlike `__init__` which is not even allowed to return a value). You've started correctly, but trying, inside `__new__` to instantiate a subclass by calling it, will just re-enter `Monomial.__new__` - you are likely getting a recursion error there.

So, even though Python does allow changing the return type of `__new__`, maybe you should consider the idea of having a factory function - independent of any class - that will return an instance of the proper class instead. Sometimes "simpler is better".

Anyway, the code for the factory approach is:

```
class Monomial(Function):

    def __init__(self, coef: int, power: int, inner=Identity()):
        super().__init__(inner)
        self.pow = power
        self.coef = coef

class Constant(Monomial):
    def __init__(self, c: int):
       super().__init__(self, coef=c, power=0)
       ...

def create_monomial(coef, power):
    if power == 0:
         return Constant(coef)
    return Monomial(coef, power)
```

(create_monomial can also be a static or class method, as you find better)

And, if you really think it would be better, a way to untangle the `__new__` method is:

```
class Monomial(Function):
    def __new__(cls, coef: int, power: int = 0, inner=Identity()):
        if power == 0:
            cls = Constant
        return super().__new__(cls)

class Constant(Monomial):
    def __init__(self, c: int, **kw):
        super().__init__(c, 0)
```

Python's instantiating mechanism will call `__init__` if the return of `__new__` is an instance of `self` - so both Monomial and Constant `__init__` will properly be called. You just have to fix Constant's `__init__` not to break on the ocasional `power = 0` parameter it will get.

Fixing the signatures would take considerably more work there, and likely involve the use of a metaclass to actually swallow, in its `__call__` method the unused `power` to Constant's `__init__`;

Also take note that the "real fix" here is that calling `super().__new__` requires passing the class explicitly - unlike other uses of `super()` where "self" or "cls" are supplied by Python. That is due to `__new__` being actually a static method - to which Python adds the `cls` when building a class, but through other mechanisms than the used by "classmethods".

Comment: Thank you! I agree the factory method is simpler, but I'd like to avoid "custom" constructors since then I'd probably use `random.choice` to choose a `Function` class at random, and thus need the interface to be consistent. So I'll probably go for the second option.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `factory method` approach? It is a nice alternative, when the exact instance type should be defined dynamically. looks like:

```
class Monomial(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def create(coef: int, power: int, inner=Identity()):
        if power == 0:
            return Constant(coef)
        else:
            return Monomial(coef, power)

x = Monomial.create(...)
```